`word.InchesToPoints` throws "com_error" when interfacing MS Word with win32com.client from pywin32
Here is my code:
import win32com.client as win32
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Add()
indent = word.InchesToPoints(0.5)
doc.Styles("Heading 2").ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = indent

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    indent  = word.InchesToPoints(0.5)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\meow\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.11\00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x8x7\_Application.py", line 179, in InchesToPoints
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(370, LCID, 1, (4, 0), ((4, 1),),Inches
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)

My question is why word.InchesToPoints doesn't work. Do I need to wrap 0.5 in some object in order to pass into InchesToPoints?

If you can't get it to work you should just be able to multiply inches by 72 to get points.
